# Maven plugin @Parameter defaultValue not injected

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a simple Mojo dto class:

```
public Output
{

  @Parameter(name="target", required=true)
  private File location;
  
  @Parameter(name="encoding", defaultValue="UTF-8")
  private String encoding;
 
// getters and setters 
}
```

I expect that the field `encoding` will contain `UTF-8` if not defined otherwise in `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- my plugin -->
            <configuration>
                <outputs>
                    <output>
                        <target>${basedir}/src/main/resources/target.json</target>
                    </output>
                </outputs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Instead I get null.

Is my expectation wrong or I'm missing something important?

Comment: How is it defined in `pom.xml`? Do you use Maven profiles?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis no pofiles, straightforward conf, example added

Comment: Do you have the binding class for Outputs and output list under it?

Answer (score 0):

One things looks suspicious in your example:

`@Parameter` annotation should usually have `property` (and `defaultValue`) and you set the `name` instead.

Assuming you're using the correct annotation (it should be this one [the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugin-tools/blob/master/maven-plugin-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.java)),
make sure you use `property` link in [this example](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#parameters) for instance.

**Update 1**

Take a look at surefire plugin source code [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/4ded070ea82076441120ff1cf0baaae7f4a47554/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L160), for example see the parameter definition (line 544):

```
 @Parameter( property = "forkCount", defaultValue = "1" )
 private String forkCount;
```

Note, that they use `property` not the `name` like you did in the question.

In the `pom.xml` you'll be able to use it like this:

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>...</version>
       <configuration>              
          <forkCount>12345</forkCount>
          ...
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If you want more complex XML (with inner elements) I'm not aware of the way to map it to the DTO like you did (I might be wrong though).

For example fabric8 maven plugin ([see the source code](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/io/fabric8/maven/plugin/mojo/build/HelmMojo.java)) doesn't use compound objects (DTOs) and injects values directly:

```
@Parameter(property = "fabric8.kubernetesManifest", defaultValue = "${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/kubernetes.yml")
private File kubernetesManifest;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your answer. I want to configure my plugin through <configuration>, not maven properties. You mean that defaultValue works only with property, not name?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Please see the update on my answer, hope it will become more clear...